# copy object using map in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

What I'm trying to do is copy object using object-array with `map` api.
like below.
decomposite the array inside of an object, and copy.

```js
 const obj = [{id: 1, arr: ['a', 'b', 'c']}];


//expected result
  const result = [
    {id: 1, arr: 'a'},
    {id: 1, arr: 'b'},
    {id: 1, arr: 'c'},
  ];
```

and also setState.

```js
  const [obj2, setObj2] = useState([{id: 1, arr: ['a', 'b', 'c']}]);

  //Both ways were invalid
  //setObj2(...obj2, obj2.arr.map(rr => obj2:rr)) 
  //setObj2(...obj2, obj2.arr : obj2.arr.map(rr => rr))

//expected result
console.log(obj2);
=> [
    {id: 1, arr: 'a'},
    {id: 1, arr: 'b'},
    {id: 1, arr: 'c'},
   ];
```

I have no idea how to make it

Comment: `obj` is an array with only one element or maybe more?

Comment: it can be more then one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using `reduce`:

```js
 const obj = [{id: 1, arr: ['a', 'b', 'c']}];

const result = obj.reduce((acc, cur) => {
   const { id, arr } = cur;
   const res = arr.map(x => ({ id, arr: x }));
   return acc.concat(res);
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) like this:

```js
const data = [{
    id: 1,
    arr: ['a', 'b', 'c']
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    arr: ['d', 'be', 'f']
  }
];


const result = data.flatMap(({id, arr}) => {
  return arr.map(item => ({id, arr: item}));
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done like this:

```
setObj2(obj2.map(item => {
   x = []
   item.arr.forEach(item2 => x.push({id:item.id, arr:item2}));
   return x;
}));
```